# How to iterate over a list of object and store data in onclick button in jstl?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am extracting and printing a list of studentBean in my jstl page. Along with this also want to create a button beside each extracted object. When user clicks on that he/she gets directed to that sudent profile.
ERROR: On clicking on any of the button I am getting always the last object.

```
<c:forEach items="${stdBeanList}" var="elements">
    <tr>            
        <td> 
                
            <form action="studentList" id="studentListForm">  
                <c:set var = "rollNum" scope = "session" value = "${elements.rollNum}"/>                                                                                        
                <input type="submit" value="view Profile" >
            </form>             
                                                
        </td>
                    
        <td>${elements.rollNum}</td>
        <td>${elements.name}</td>
        <td>${elements.grade}</td>
        <td>${elements.section}</td>
        <td>${elements.gender}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You can set `${elements.rollNum}` value inside hidden input i.e : `<input type="hidden" name="rollNum" value="${elements.rollNum}">` put this line inside form and access this value using `request.getParameter("rollNum")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="studentList" id="studentListForm">  
<c:forEach items="${stdBeanList}" var="elements"  varStatus="loop">
    <tr>            
       
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="${elements.rollNum}" name="studRollNo"></td>           
        <td>${elements.rollNum}</td>
        <td>${elements.name}</td>
        <td>${elements.grade}</td>
        <td>${elements.section}</td>
        <td>${elements.gender}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>  
          <tr>
           
         <td><input type="submit" value="view Profile"></td>
        
        </tr> 
</form>
```

Servlet:

```
   String rollNo=request.getParameter("studRollNo"); // if multiple values of checkbox nedded then use 'getParameterValues("studRollNo")'

       //Your logic to get Student details from Database and store in Object
      //set the object in attribute(i.e:Session or request)
     //redirect to JSP
    //populate the Attribute on JSP suing JSTL
```